# Compact set of real numbers with countably many limit points.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Construct a compact set of real numbers whose limit points form a countable set.

My example: Let $E_1=\{1\}\cup \{1+1/n: n\in \mathbb{N}\},$
$E_2=\{1/2\}\cup \{1/2+1/n: n>2\},$ $E_3=\{1/3\}\cup \{1/3+1/n: n>6\},\dots,$ $E_k=\{1/k\}\cup \{1/k+1/n: n>k(k-1)\},\dots$

Let $F=\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k$. It's easy to see that $F$ is bounded and $F$ is closed because $F'=\{1/j\}_{j\geqslant 1}$. So $F$ is compact set. Also $F'\sim \mathbb{N}$.

Is my example true?

Comment: What is "l.p."?

Comment: Presumably limit points.

Comment: sorry. l.p.=limit points. So what about my example?

Answer (score 4):

I agree that $F$ is bounded and countable.

However $F$ is not closed. $\{0\}$ is a limit point that is not in $F$.

$F \cup \{0\}$ is a compact set.

Comment: Why $\{0\}$ is a limit point of $F$?

Comment: $(1/n)_{n \ge 1}$ is a sequence of points of $F$ that converges to $0$.

Comment: So what? I am always considering $1/k+1/n$ for fixed $k$. But you are talking about $1/n$?!

Comment: That is not what you wrote. You wrote $E_k=\{1/k\}\cup \{1/k+1/n: n>k(k-1)\},\dots$ and $F=\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k$. So $1/n$ belongs to $F$ for all $n \ge 1$.

Comment: Sorry! Really $\{0\}$ is also a limit point. Thank you very much for your remark!